# Firebase Real-Time Database what would happen to concurrent requests in this case?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have 2 nodes in my database `items` and `my_items`.

I have this function that does a `multi-path update`, this function deletes an item from `items` and adds it to the user's `my_items`:

I secured the `my_items` node in a way that you can only write to it if the item exists in `items`, otherwise it fails:

```
private void getItem(String uid, String item_key) {    
  Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();

  //delete item
  updates.put("items/" + item_key, null);

  //give the item to the user
  updates.put("my_items/" + uid + "/" + item_key, itemObject);

  mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(updates);
}
```

### Question (In theory):

- Knowing that Firebase Database handles requests one by one.

If users A,B,C,D called the `getItem(..)` function for the same `item id` together at the same time:

**Does this makes sense:**

1. lets say A's request reached the server first and `Succeeds`

(now the item was deleted from `items` and added to user A at `my_items`)

2. B: `Fails`

(because the item no longer exists in `items`, so security rule of `my_items` prevents this)

3. C: `Fails`

(same reason)

4. D: `Fails`

(same reason)

**Is this what would happen ? Or I got this wrong ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database processes (write) operations sequentially. So any previous write operation will have been completed before the next one is processed. That means that any data written by a previous user will indeed be present in the `root` variable in security rules evaluation for later write operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand what you said. So according to my above theory is it true that no matter how many users called the function only one must succeed and others must fail?

Comment: That might depend on how you implement the rules. I'm reluctant to give a blanket "your approach will work " on the abstract description, hence explaining how the system works. Isolated multi-user operations can definitely be implemented with transactions and/or multi-path updates and security rules, so if you run into problems I recommend posting a new question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can have a look.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your help and for your time. I will soon ask about what would the best security rule for `items` and `my_items` be to achieve this theory. Hopefully you will check it.

Answer (score 1):

This [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86) discusses atomic operations. RTDB acts on requests as they arrive. RTDB processes events as they arrive. There is another question that might be relevant [Does Firebase always guarantee added events in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280940/does-firebase-always-guarantee-added-events-in-order)

> You can ... do this in a single atomic update to both locations:
>
> JavaScript
>
> ```
> var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
> // Generate a new push ID for the new post
> var newPostRef = ref.child("posts").push();
> var newPostKey = newPostRef.key();
> // Create the data we want to update
> var updatedUserData = {};
> updatedUserData["user/posts/" + newPostKey] = true;
> updatedUserData["posts/" + newPostKey] = {
>   title: "New Post",
>   content: "Here is my new post!"
> };
> // Do a deep-path update
> ref.update(updatedUserData, function(error) {
>   if (error) {
>     console.log("Error updating data:", error);
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> Java
>
> ```
> Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
> // Generate a new push ID for the new post
> Firebase newPostRef = ref.child("posts").push();
> String newPostKey = newPostRef.getKey();
> // Create the data we want to update
> Map newPost = new HashMap();
> newPost.put("title", "New Post");
> newPost.put("content", "Here is my new post!");
> Map updatedUserData = new HashMap();
> updatedUserData.put("users/posts/" + newPostKey, true);
> updatedUserData.put("posts/" + newPostKey, newPost);
> // Do a deep-path update
> ref.updateChildren(updatedUserData, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
>    @Override
>    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
>        if (firebaseError != null) {
>            System.out.println("Error updating data: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
>        }
>    }
> });
> ```
>
> Objective-C
>
> ```
> Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com"];
> // Generate a new push ID for the new post
> Firebase *newPostRef = [[ref childByAppendingPath:@"posts"] childByAutoId];
> NSString *newPostKey = newPostRef.key;
> NSString *updateUserPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/posts/%@", newPostKey];
> NSString *updatePostPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"posts/%@", newPostKey];
> // Create the data we want to update
> NSMutableDictionary *updatedUserData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
> [updatedUserData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:updateUserPath];
> [updatedUserData setValue:@{@"title": @"New Post", @"content": @"Here is my new post!"} forKey:updatePostPath];
> // Do a deep-path update
> [ref updateChildValues:updatedUserData withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
>     if (error) {
>         NSLog(@"Error updating data: %@", error.debugDescription);
>     }
> }];
> ```
>
> Swift
>
> ```
> "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com") // Generate a new push
> ID for the new post let newPostRef =
> ref.childByAppendingPath("posts").childByAutoId() let newPostKey =
> newPostRef.key // Create the data we want to update let
> updatedUserData = ["users/posts/(newPostKey)": true,
> "posts/(newPostKey)": > ["title": "New Post", "content": "Here is my
> new post!"]] // Do a deep-path update
> ref.updateChildValues(updatedUserData, withCompletionBlock: { (error,
> ref) -> > Void in
>     if (error) {
>         print("Error updating data: (error.description)")
>     } })
> ```
>
> Deep path updates let you write cleaner code and easily denormalize
> data across multiple nodes in your Firebase database.

Comment: My question is not how to do the multi-path update. I just want to know if the example that I gave above makes sense given the security rule that I wrote