# Understanding (root) in firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

From what I understand `root.child(...)` in firebase security rules represents the `old data` at the child.

Lets say multiple users A,B,C,D updated the same child node together.

Server gets them likes this:

1. A first.
2. B next.
3. C next.
4. D next.

**My Question:**

When B is processed. Shouldn't `root` hold the data that was updated by A ?

Comment: Likely answer below. If that's not it, please edit your question to include the [minimal code and security rules that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as seeing what you do will make it much more likely someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send these as a single write operation, they are processed atomically so they are either all applied in one go or none of them are applied. The `root` will **not** be updated until they are all applied, so only for the next write operation you send.

If you require an explicit ordering of the write operation, send them as separate write operations to the database.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the question. It seems you thought A,B,C,D are writes by the same user. But they are the writes done by different users.

Comment: users A , B , C , D are writing to the same node at the same time. That's what I meant. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: If they are separate writes, the `root` variable will contain all committed previous writes. Instead of commenting here with clarifications, can you update your question to contain a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Frank thanks for your reply. I have a problem with a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088972/firebase-real-time-database-what-would-happen-to-concurrent-requests-in-this-cas) and I am stuck and don't want to repeat the question here. I would really appreciate if you look into it and give me any advice.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to validate your hypotheses on what is causing the problem you have, but leads to us chasing a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's reallymore likely we can find the root cause with a [minimal, complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which the linked question unfortunately also doesn't contain. We'll really need to see what database calls you make inn what order, what rules those calls are evaluated against, and what results you get back.

Comment: I appreciate that you looked into the question, and I don't want to fill this comment section. My question is not a problem I faced. I just want to know if I understand the realtime database request handling right. Can you please tell me on the other question what you need to understand more and I will update. Thanks really.